# add html plugin to django

Tags: html, django, plugins

I am new to django and I have been using the plugins as child's to sections.text/accordion/ etc.   In one  page I want to have a google map snippet inside the column , but as a plugin not via the google_map app and inside the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py ...
So in general  wonder if it is possible to have  an html plugin that will be added also via the cms like the other plugins and in that html section to do things like, image gallery for example , google maps,animations,  forms etc ...

Comment: If you know Python and have had some experience with Django, what you're trying to do is not so difficult. You can waste time looking for *plugins* which match your exact needs or you can write one for yourself in the matter of a few hours.

Comment: "I have been using the plugins as child's to sections" "it is possible to have an html plugin that will be added also via the cms" => err, __which__ cms are you talking about here ? Django is not a cms and don't have "plugins".

Comment: text plugin, row plugin  they come with the system.  Now I am trying to add a new plug in via a new class in models  coms_plugins

Comment: sorry meant cms_plugins

Comment: based on [this](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-accordion/blob/master/djangocms_accordion/cms_plugins.py) I assume it is about django cms?

Comment: is not it enough to register the plugin in the plugin_pool and  in models and anatomy.  still I get an error of    plugin_pool.register_plugin(ArticlePlugin)
NameError: name 'ArticlePlugin' is not defined.

Comment: Yes version 1.6.1

Comment: used this : http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-2.2.x/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html   and in the html  started a the google map. thank you xyres